# How to use --archive-entries options with JFrog CLI search and download commands

Tags: artifactory, conan, jfrog-cli

I want to search and download only particular file from the conan package archive(i.e. `conan_package.tgz`) using JFrog CLI. I have tried following, but it didn't work.

`jfrog rt s */*conan/ --archive-entries=conaninfo.txt`

Even though there is a file `conaninfo.txt` in the `.tgz` file, its returning empty.

Is this possible to do that using CLI?

Comment: Make sure "Archive Search Enabled" is checked in Administration | Artifactory | General settings